# Meaning of **Canonical metric** on complex manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, complex-geometry

What is the meaning of **Canonical metric** on complex manifolds ?

Comment: In general there is no such thing in the obvious interpretation of the words. For example multiplication with $\lambda\ne 0$ is a homeomorphism $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$, hence the set of points at canonical distance $1$ from the origin should be scale-invariant, which is impossible

Comment: it would be better, if you show the context...

Comment: See [this presentation](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/seminars/lecturesmath/file_uploads/canonical_metrics.pdf) by Yau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a compact Kahler manifold $M$, canonical metric can mean: 
(i) Kahler-Enstein metric or (ii) metric with constant scalar curvature which is the extremal metric of the Calabi functional $\displaystyle\int_M R^2$.

You can find more details from the book [Canonical Metrics in Kahler Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PY4I9A) by by Gang Tian.